# Converting ordered dictionaries with different values

Tags: python

I have an ordered dictionary of ordered dictionaries, now if the value of the key if its a list I need to create a list of dictionaries with using all the values inside the list like this,

```
dee= OrderedDict([('b', [1,9]), ('a', ['{}','{}'])])
eee=[OrderedDict([('b', 1),('a',{})]),OrderedDict([('b', 9),('a',{})])]
```

Now how do i recursively go inside the dictionary like ab and create a list with dictionaries with same keys and different values.

```
ab=OrderedDict([('part', ['8888822701B', '8889012006B', '8889012013B', '8889012014B', '8889012016C', '8889012019B', '8889012020C', '8889012021D', '8889012022B']), ('file', ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']), ('estimatedtime', ['100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100']), ('signature', ['{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}']), ('otherpartsignature', ['{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}'])])
```

Comment: could you put an example of what you have, what you wish to have as result and what you did so far pls? I'm not really getting what you need :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all keys and create new Ordered dicts on the first key processed, the later keys add to the earlier created dicts.

For each key you iterate over all values and put them into single Ordered dicts that you add to a list (this works as long as your input value-lists all have the same amount of data):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ab = OrderedDict([
    ('part', ['8888822701B', '8889012006B', '8889012013B', '8889012014B', '8889012016C', 
              '8889012019B', '8889012020C', '8889012021D', '8889012022B']), 
    ('file', ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']), 
    ('estimatedtime', ['100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100']), 
    ('signature', ['{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}']), 
    ('otherpartsignature', ['{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}'])])

listOfDicts = []
for key,values in ab.items():
    if not dicts: # create all new OrderedDicts when processing the values of first key
        for v in values:
            listOfDicts.append(OrderedDict({key:v}))
    else:
        for idx,v in enumerate(values): # use the earlier created Ordered dicts and add to them
            d = listOfDicts[idx]
            d[key]=v

print(listOfDicts)
```

Output:

```
[OrderedDict([('part', '8888822701B'), ('file', '0'), ('estimatedtime', '100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012006B'), ('file', '1'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012013B'), ('file', '2'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012014B'), ('file', '3'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012016C'), ('file', '4'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012019B'), ('file', '5'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012020C'), ('file', '6'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012021D'), ('file', '7'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')]), 
 OrderedDict([('part', '8889012022B'), ('file', '8'), ('estimatedtime', ' 100'), ('signature', '{}'), ('otherpartsignature', '{}')])]
```